# What exactly the meaning of structure pointer

Tags: c

```c
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left, *right;
};
```

What exactly the meaning of this `struct Node *`? Is the function below returning a pointer to a Node?

```
struct Node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct Node* node = new(struct Node);
    node->data = data;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return (node);
}
```

Comment: Yes, a `struct Node *` is a pointer to a `struct Node`, just the same as an `int *` is a pointer to an `int`.   Note that the code shown in the question does not define a type `Node`; it only defines a type `struct Node`.  The function is returning a pointer to a `struct Node`.  Note that `new(struct Node)` is a C++ construct; it is not valid C code (unless there's a macro behind the scenes converting `new` into a call to `malloc()` or something similar).

Comment: struct node is fully considered as a type . Like int ,float . So struct Node* is capable of returning pointer of struct Node* type.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Node;
```

Is the name of your struct.

> What exactly the meaning of this struct Node*?

```
struct Node* node;
```

You're declaring a ***pointer to the struct `Node`*** that needs to be allocated with some memory. There is no `new` keyword in C. You need to use `malloc()` to allocate the required bytes of memory. You can allocate that like this:

```
struct Node* node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

> Is it returning a pointer to a Node?

This line:

```
return (node);
```

Returns the type of `struct Node*` to the function.